# GWT Window redirection problem

Tags: gwt

Hi I have this code in my gwt app which purpose is to chage to URL as follows:

```
public void goToSignUpPage(boolean isDeployed) {
    String url = (isDeployed == true ? "signup.html" : "signup.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997");
    Window.Location.replace(url);
```

However what happens it redirects into this URL:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/mygwtapp/signup.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Where the working URL is this:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/signup.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

BTW, mygwtapp is the gwt module named defined in MyGwtApp.gwt.xml

```
<module rename-to='mygwtapp'>
```

Any ideas why the URL is appended by the gwt module name? Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed was to add in [GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/index.html?com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html) to get the full URL for your web application without it appending to the module name.

Try this out:

```
public void goToSignUpPage() {
    String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "signup.html";

    if(!GWT.isProdMode()) {
        Window.alert("We are in development mode!");
        url += "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997";
    }

    Window.Location.replace(url);
}
```

I've also removed your parameter "isDeployed" and replaced it with [GWT.isProdMode()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html) within the method to check if you're in production or development mode.

With a paramater:

```
public void goToSignUpPage(Boolean isDeployed) {

    String url = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "signup.html";

    if(!isDeployed) {
        url += "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997";
    }

    Window.Location.replace(url);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, it works now. However my code cannot user GWT.isProdMode() as it is unresolved error, I am not sure my gwt app is based on GWT 2.0.3

Comment: Ah well that's strange. I'm not quite sure when they introduced that method. I updated the answer for others who may view the question.

Comment: Actually, I just used GWT.isScript() instead of GWT.isProdMode()

Comment: ah nice - I completely looked over that.